# Update total books excluding expired

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with following query which updates total_books for each category

```
UPDATE book_categories C, books P, (SELECT cat_id, book_id, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_BOOKS FROM book_category GROUP BY cat_id) PC SET C.total_books=PC.TOTAL_BOOKS WHERE PC.cat_id=C.cat_id AND P.book_id=PC.book_id AND P.is_expired=false
```

The problem with this query is it does not skip expired books. I need a clue how to skip the expired books.

Here is the schema:

```
Create table books (
    book_id Bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
is_expired Bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
Primary Key ( book_id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

Create table book_categories (
    cat_id Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    total_books Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Primary Key (cat_id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

Create table book_category (
     book_category_id Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cat_id Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     book_id Bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Primary Key ( book_category_id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

Alter table book_category add Foreign Key (book_id) references books (book_id) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table book_category add Foreign Key (cat_id) references book_categories (cat_id) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
```

Comment: I have taken the liberty of formatting your post. Please do take care of this next time; 11 months and 32 questions should be enough to learn Markdown syntax!

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, I added spaces but some how they are only appeared in first paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the inside query should look like this:

```
(SELECT cat_id, book_id, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_BOOKS 
FROM book_category bc
JOIN books b 
ON bc.book_id = b.book_id
WHERE b.is_expired ='false'
GROUP BY cat_id)
```

Comment: there is one issue, the inner query does not return anything if there are no expired books, how can I force it to return 0 if there are no matches?

Comment: take a look at mysql [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)' =)